# Python .str method not working inside an iterrow function

Tags: python, pandas, iterator

I have a pandas dataframe full of file locations.  I'm trying to iterate through each row, open the file and save it in a different format.  I pull the file name out of the location string as part of the path to save it.

That said, slicing the location string works outside of the `iterrows` function, but throws an error inside of it.

This code works by itself:

`mpo_list['location'].str[31:]`

When I put it in the below iterrow function, I get an error.

```
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path

for i, row in mpo_list.iterrows():
    im = Image.open(Path(row['location']))
    picture = row['location'].str[31:]
    im.save('D:\\2018_Formost\\2018-12\\Photos\\'+picture, format = 'JPEG')
```

This is the error it throws:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-483e2a21fc33> in <module>
      2     im = Image.open(Path(row['location']))
      3    # picture = row['location'].str[31:]
----> 4     im.save('D:\\2018_Formost\\2018-12\\Photos\\'+row['location'].str[31:], format = 'JPEG')

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Can anyone see what mistake I'm making?

Comment: try `picture = row['location'][31:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row['location']` is already of type string, so you only need to access the right indices. Try this instead:

```
picture = row['location'][31:]
```